# Is there a firm or preliminary decision on which modules will leave Core for 8?

Tags: 8

I seem to recall I've seen a more than one discussion about breaking out certain less than maintained modules from Core. They would presumably be moved to contrib instead. Currently I can't find any information on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue report for that ([[Meta] Make core maintainable](http://drupal.org/node/1255674)), but nothing has been decided yet. As you can see, there are different opinions about what to remove, and what to keep.
catch, the latest maintainer added to Drupal 8, [expressed his opinion on that](http://drupal.org/node/1255674#comment-4908744); the same did [Dries](http://drupal.org/node/1255674#comment-4917848), [chx](http://drupal.org/node/1255674#comment-4906614), [Crell](http://drupal.org/node/1255674#comment-4915922), and [eaton](http://drupal.org/node/1255674#comment-4914450) (just to cite some of them). There is an agreement about some of the modules to remove, but there isn't a complete agreement.

That issue report is not marked as postponed, and a new issue report has been opened ([Establish heuristics for core feature evaluation](http://drupal.org/node/1273344)).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Seeing the issue title, I understand why my searches failed to yield anything relevant.